# Best way to do full page alert in ionic (like an alarm clock, or the phone app)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-popup

So without getting too technical I am trying to create an app that brings up a full page notification like an alarm does on android and iOS (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sm4t.png)). Is there anyway to do this with ionic? if not what would be the best way to alert someone in a way that has multiple options swipe left to do X swipe right to do Y, or press option C at the bottom kind of thing. The only thing I can think of that do this are phone calls and alarms, any ideas? If I absolutely have to I can make it a push notification that when touched opens this page, but ideally it would be a full page notification in the first place (that is kinda the whole idea of the app)

Comment: This question is too broad and not a good fit for Stack Overflow.  This site is for specific programming questions, not "here's my spec how do I build this?"

Answer (score 2):

refer [Push Notifications documentation](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/#handling-notifications). and [$ionicLoading](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/)

```
scope.$on('cloud:push:notification', function(data) {
  var msg = data.message;
  $ionicLoading.show({
      templateUrl: 'url of notification screen with a button to $ionicLoading.hide()'
    })
});
```

This will show the notification fullScreen. The screen can be autoclosed for a duration or on `$ionicLoading.hide()`